# How to read a value from odata object

Tags: c#, json, odata

```
var response = await Client.GetAsync("/dev/rateservices/EDisclaimers/Format").ConfigureAwait(false);
var x = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

I want to read value of id when `name = US.CentralizedRefi.Tier1_MoreInfo_Disclaimer` from below object(Value of var X). how to do that?

> {"@odata.context":"http://localhost/dev/rateservices/$metadata#EDisclaimers","value":[{"id":1,"name":"Standard.TypicalTransactions","effectiveDate":"2014-05-01","expiryDate":null},{"id":2,"name":"Standard.AdditionalFees","effectiveDate":"2014-05-01","expiryDate":null},{"id":3,"name":"Standard.EndorsementOnlySupport","effectiveDate":"2014-05-01","expiryDate":null},{"id":4,"name":"Standard.CPL","effectiveDate":"2016-09-21","expiryDate":null},{"id":5,"name":"LimitedCoverage","effectiveDate":"2015-11-01","expiryDate":null},{"id":6,"name":"CallForFeeEndorsement","effectiveDate":"2015-11-01","expiryDate":null},{"id":7,"name":"UserDefined","effectiveDate":"2015-11-01","expiryDate":null},{"id":8,"name":"BUSREQ_GL-1310-CFPB","effectiveDate":"2015-11-01","expiryDate":null},{"id":9,"name":"US.CentralizedRefi.Tier1_MoreInfo_Disclaimer","effectiveDate":"2015-11-01","expiryDate":null}]}

Comment: are you deserializing this into an object representation? If so, please provide object. If not, you might consider doing so if you are going to be manipulating the data

Answer (score 1):

You need to use predicate with [$filter query option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309461%28v=crm.7%29.aspx) in the end of your query. If you would like to use equal operator with filtering query option, your query should look like this :

```
http://localhost/dev/rateservices/EDisclaimers?$filter=name  eq 'US.CentralizedRefi.Tier1_MoreInfo_Disclaimer'
```

Above query returns records which matches with above filtering option.